# Cucumber/Webrat user session flash[:notice] issue still exists in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, webrat

Hi I ran in this issue a while ago...

[authlogic flash[:notice] does not show up in cucumber webrat step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240927/authlogic-flashnotice-does-not-show-up-in-cucumber-webrat-step)

And it looks like it still exisits in rails 3 this was a suggested fix.

```
    class RackRailsCookieHeaderHack
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
    if headers['Set-Cookie'] && headers['Set-Cookie'].respond_to?(:collect!)
      headers['Set-Cookie'].collect! { |h| h.strip }
    end
    [status, headers, body]
  end
end

config.after_initialize do
  ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.insert_before(ActionController::Base.session_store, RackRailsCookieHeaderHack)
end
```

this fixed the issue with 2.3.8... I had to place it in the config/environment/cucumber.rb

but in Rails 3 this file is not available anymore and in config/environment/test.rb I cannot inject something in the middleware

according the lighthouse bugtracker this should be fixed... can someone confirm that this problem still exists with Rails 3? Any help would be great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution.

I replaced webrat with capybara and everything is good.