# test user sign up with cucumber - failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, devise

i'm trying to test user sign up. using rails+devise 1.1.rc2
I have this test:

```
Given I am on the landing page
When I go to the registration page
And I fill in "Firstname" with "F"
And I fill in "Lastname" with "L"
And I fill in "Country" with "C"
And I fill in "State" with "S"
And I fill in "City" with "C"
And I fill in "Email" with "me@gmail.com"
And I fill in "Password" with "password"
And I fill in "Password Confirmation" with "password"
And I press "Register"
Then I should see "You have registered successfully. If enabled, a confirmation was sent your e-mail."
```

This is the error snippet:

```
expected the following element's content to include "You have registered successfully. If enabled, a confirmation was sent your e-mail.":
You are being redirected. (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:145:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/'
features/registration.feature:42:in `Then I should see "You have registered successfully. If enabled, a confirmation was sent your e-mail."
```

I think it's got something to do with a redirect, not sure how to fix this? But in my app_controller.rb i have this so the user is taken to the dashboard page...

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  "/dashboard"
end
```

its  just the test thats failing, the actual registration functionality is fine.

Comment: that's terrible presentation... please make it clean if you want someone to read

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in another stack overflow post.  Basically the flash message does not persist through redirect_to, but render :action => xxxx will make it work.

[authlogic flash[:notice] does not show up in cucumber webrat step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240927/authlogic-flashnotice-does-not-show-up-in-cucumber-webrat-step)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend upgrading Devise to be the latest (1.2, at current writing) release.

Then I would debug what's happening here by putting `Then show me the page` above the step that's failing. I think your flash message is wrong.

Comment: thanks Ryan, i didn't know about launchy, i've upgraded to 1.2 and added the step in, i've installed launchy but keep getting this error message:  "Sorry, you need to install launchy to open pages: `gem install launchy`" - i have however run the system and registered and checked the flash message, it matches what's expected 100%. The You are being redirected. might be the issue...am playing around with it a bit more, all suggestions welcome

Comment: no luck so far...interesting that the functionality works when the system is run, but the cucumber test fails...

Comment: something similar is happening for login. When i go the login page and login, the cucumber test doesnt find the flash message so the step fails. I've checked which page its on and it seems to be on login instead of redirecting to my root page. Of course when i run the system, it's all just dandy. i'm not sure how these redirects work, but devise+cucumber is turning out to be painful. have you had this issue?