# Devise/Cucumber - Adding a step which confirm a user exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, devise, factory-bot

I'm new to cucumber and I find following snippets to test the Devise login feature. However it seems one more step missing, and I didn't find any solution:

```
Given /^that a confirmed user exists$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Here the following code:

## features/authentication/session.feature

```
Feature: Session handling
  In order to use the site
  As a registered user
  I need to be able to login and logout

Background: 
  Given that a confirmed user exists

Scenario Outline: Logging in
  Given I am on the login page
  When I fill in "user_email" with "<email>"
  And I fill in "user_password" with "<password>"
  And I press "Sign in"
  Then I should <action>
  Examples:
    |         email       |  password   |              action             |
    | minimal@example.com |  test1234   | see "Signed in successfully"    |
    | bad@example.com     |  password   | see "Invalid email or password" |

Scenario: Logging out
  Given I am logged in
  When I go to the sign out link
  Then I should see "Signed out successfully"
```

## features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb

```
# Session
Given /^I am logged in$/ do
  visit path_to('the login page')
  fill_in('user_email', :with => @user.email)
  fill_in('user_password', :with => @user.password)
  click_button('Sign in')
  if defined?(Spec::Rails::Matchers)
    page.should have_content('Signed in successfully')
  else
    assert page.has_content?('Signed in successfully')
  end
end
```

## spec/factories/user.rb

```
Factory.define :minimal_user, :class => User do |u|
  u.username 'minimal'
  u.email 'minimal@example.com'
  u.password 'test1234'
  u.password_confirmation 'test1234'
end
```

Here the link to the [orginal code](http://johnwyles.com/2010/04/24/turning-a-pickcle-into-a-cucumber/)

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title says "validate that a user exists", but that's might not be what you need to do there -- your `Given` steps don't need to be asserting that something worked, they invoke code to create the application state for your scenario.  Of course, they're still tests since they can still fail.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
Given /^that a confirmed user exists$/ do
  Factory.create(:minimal_user)
end
```

That will create and save a new confirmed user from your factory definition so the rest of the Scenario can proceed.

Comment: No problem! I just edited to add some more information RE: given steps.

Comment: OK Daniel, So I'll change the title. I have also 2 errors resulting of that code. I would be very pleased if you can give me a hand on this. I add the failed steps as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have a couple structural issues, probably what's happening is your Scenario Outline, which runs before every Scenario in the feature, is signing in and then when you run your Given I am logged in step, it doesn't find the message since you're already logged in (I think the Devise login page forwards active users to the root by default).  The other issue is that it looks like @user isn't being defined anywhere.  You might want to read the excellent official cucumber docs: http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki

Comment: Thanks again Daniel for your time! Benoit

Answer (score 1):

To complete the Daniel's answer and because I enable the Devise confirmable module, I should add a line in my fixture in order to tell that the user is confirmed.

For example:

```
Factory.define :minimal_user, :class => User do |u|
  u.username 'minimal'
  u.email 'minimal@example.com'
  u.password 'test1234'
  u.password_confirmation 'test1234'
  u.confirmed_at 'here the date you want'
end
```

Also, debug steps you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136334/rails-cucumber-webrat-redirect-to-flashnotice-not-working) are very useful.

Hope it helps some people.

Comment: In the future, you shouldn't add this as an answer. Instead you should update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(::) failed steps (::)

expected #has_content?("Signed in successfully") to return true, got false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:108:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/authentication/session.feature:16:in `Then I should <action>'

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:43:in `/^I am logged in$/'
features/authentication/session.feature:23:in `Given I am logged in'
```